# Excel conditional statement with dates

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to make a conditional formatting rule in Excel where I have two conditions before a cell in highlighted. So say I have columns A and B, where A is a date and column B may or may not be blank. E.g.:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1/3/15 | 1 |
| 1/5/16 |  |
| 1/9/16 |  |
| 1/3/16 | 2 |
| 1/8/16 | 5 |
| 1/7/16 | 6 |
| 1/7/22 | 6 |
| 1/7/23 |  |
| 8/23/23 |  |
| 8/23/23 | 3 |

I want to make a rule where I go through each cell in column A. The cell will be highlighted if both of these conditions are met:

1. The cell next to it (in column B) is blank
2. The date in the cell is greater than tomorrow's date

Is there a formula I can put into the conditional formatting rules to make this happen?

Edit: On the off chance someone else could use this later, this is the rule I used to get it to work:

```
=AND(ISBLANK($B1),$A1<(TODAY()+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Put in column A conditional formatting with this formula:

```
=IF(AND($B1="",$A1>TODAY()+1),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No need `IF()`. Just `=AND($B1="",$A1>TODAY()+1)` is enough for CF.